# How do I create a document with section and subsection numbers, but no chapter numbers?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

I'm trying to create a research protocol document that uses sections and subsections, but does not have chapters. For example, if I use the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1.5in}
\textbf{Introducing a Bayesian Nonparametric Beta-Mixture Item Response Model}\\
\end{center}
\pagebreak

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagebreak

\section{Synopsis}

\section{Abbreviations and Acronyms}

\section{Background}

\end{document}
```

the chapter number is set to 0, and my sections are numbered as 0.1, 0.2, etc.

What I want to do is to have my sections numbered as 1.0, 2.0, etc., and my subsections numbered as 1.1, 1.2, etc. I know that there has to be a way to do this. I just don't know what it is.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` instead of `report`? The only thing to achieve that then remains is the trailing `.0` to the section counter…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `article` class. Also you renew the command that printsout the section counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{a}
\subsection{b}
\section{c}
\subsection{d}

\end{document}
```

[image]